# Forms Instead of Long Admins?

Tags: django, django-admin

My Post model is getting quite extensive and long in admin. I'm wondering at what point I should use forms, instead? Is there a way to break admin entry into multiple pages, or tabs?

Comment: If my answer solved your problem, mark it as accepted, please. It's a good practice in StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use [`fieldsets`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.fieldsets) with `classes = collapse`?

It's a handy way of orginizing long forms in Django Admin.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I like admin over forms since articles are not created by the public. Fieldsets are just what I wanted.

Comment: Glad I could help!